# Find the value of $\sin({-11\pi}/{3})$?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: .]

In the image the rotation starts from point 1 and rotates clockwise until 7 comes at point 3

Now in this question I know how to solve it by using $\sin(2n\pi-\theta)$ but if I try to solve it in this way

$$\sin(\frac{-11\pi}{3})=
\sin(\frac{-11\pi}{3}\cdot\frac{180}{\pi})=
-\sin(660^\circ)=
-\sin(90^\circ\cdot7+30^\circ)=
-\cos(30^\circ)= 
-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

Now as there is negative outside the bracket we should move clockwise in the Cartesian plane, right? If I start from the $+x$ axis then after moving seven times I would arrive at $-x$ axis. As it is $+30^\circ$ the angle should lie in II quadrant and as it is sin the value should be +ve. So the answer should be $-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ but the answer is $+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. So my doubt is which axis should I start from in the Cartesian plane if the movement is clockwise and also if the movement is anti clockwise or counter clockwise? Which axis should my point 1 be in?Sorry I went through the question again and I saw that I had made a mistake in one of the steps.Thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I honestly cannot follow your question, you have used a lot of nonstandard notation, and the standard notation which you have used is used in a way that is not clear.  Please format your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is under root?

Comment: Why in particular would you convert to degrees and to cosine? Besides $30º$ is in the *first* quadrant.

Comment: Have you tried typing each of the steps of your rewriting into a calculator and seeing where the value changes? That should tell you where something is going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Since $\sin x$ has period $2\pi$, one has
$$\sin\Bigl(-\dfrac{11\pi}3\Bigr)=\sin\Bigl(-\dfrac{11\pi}3+4\pi\Bigr).$$

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly concluded $\sin(7\pi/2+x)=\cos x$. Shifting by two periods, $\sin(7\pi/2+x)=\sin(x-\pi/2)=-\cos x$.